# Which Exception is most appropriate here?

Tags: java, restlet, sanitization

I am validating some input from a Restlet URL in a utility method (that way if the behavior I take changes, I only change it one place, yay). The legalName essentially validates the value as being alphaNumeric, but I may allow other characters soon.

I try to keep my Exceptions to make sense - what Exception would be the best in this scenario?

```
public static String getProperty(Request request, String key) {
    String value = request.getAttributes().get(key).toString();
    // unless something is specifically text, it is a property
    if(legalName(value)) return value;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);

}
```

My thoughts are:

- IllegalArgumentException - the key directly leads to an invalid result
- IllegalStateException - we're trying to use a non-conforming value
- No exception - return an empty string and log the fact that a breach was made
- No exception - remove any undesireable characters, return the sanitized string, and log the fact

Surely I'm not the first person to have to validate input before :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions like this should be thrown when the property is stored, not retrieved. Check [Restlet validation](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/g2/367-restlet.html) for that.

If you prefer to stick to your solution:

- rename the method to `validateName(..)` and let it throw the exception. If it doesn't - return the value.
- `javax.validation.ValidationException` looks the better option, but you can use any of the two `IllegalXException` you mentioned. Just make sure they have a more detailed message.

Comment: Often times it won't be stored, it would simply used as a parameter. It might still end up in a query though. My thought was if I sanitize it as soon as it enters the system, I know I'll have safe inputs.

Comment: Oh I like that first bullet option a lot. That's also better because anything else that uses the validation doesn't have to do the throwing, meaning if it changes (as mentioned below and using a validation framework) it's in one place I change it, not a dozen. As for validation on storage, I see what you mean now. Essentially intercepting it before it even gets to my code. I will look into this for sure. Thanks!

Comment: So here's what I think I'm going to do: I currently have two types of validation: user text (where I escape any special characters) and alphaNumeric. If it grows beyond that, I'll look at the server side validation, and if that doesn't pan out, I'll move to a more robust validation frame work. If it stays at these two, I can safely leave it be.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be invalid user input, so first I'd go for a ValidationException of some kind and use a validation framework instead of managing it all yourself. If not the ValidationException, then IllegalArgumentException probably makes the most sense out of your listed choices.

Comment: Validation framework? I guess I wasn't exactly aware of them, but I suppose there's a framework for everything. Can you recommend a very light weight validation framework?

Comment: Spring's data binding and validation framework is very good.  You don't have to use the rest of Spring to get benefit from it.

Comment: +1 to @duffymo's [Spring validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) is a good one. In combination with that, check out [JSR 303 Bean Validation](http://people.redhat.com/~ebernard/validation/). Hibernate is the [reference implementation](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), and Spring supports it (see section 5.7 under previous Spring link).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Custom(Your Own) Exception Class .Depending upon the situation or validation you can throw it with proper message.
For Ex: 1.For Illegal Argument Exception case Handle that block of code in try catch and in catch throw your own  Exception with Proper message.

Comment: I could make my own Exception class, but I prefer to use the standard ones when doing standard things. (Effective Java 2nd ed Item 60: Favor the use of standard exceptions.) I didn't add the message yet, although whatever Exception I end up using it will have an appropriate message :-)